# Facebook Graph API: Missing posts from feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've read so many posts regarding this issue, nevertheless no solution was found.

I'm using [the graph explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) with ALL permissions selected (on both "User Data Permissions" and "Extended Permissions")

Trying to query a group feed via: `/{group-id}/feed`

And some posts are missing.

I saw that someone somewhere wrote that FQL will probably overcome this limitation - but [Facebook announced that they are going to suppress FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/).

**----------------[Try it Yourself]---------------------**

1. Join the group "IT Security" (This is just an example). You can find the group with facebook.com/6340489103
2. find a post by "Gabor Nagy". Tip: after joining the group, you can access the post directly via "facebook.com/10152587882559104".
3. Go to the graph explorer (link above)
4. type /10152587882559104 which is /{post_id}
5. did you receive "code: 100"?

{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported post request.", 
    "type": "GraphMethodException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}

1. try other posts and see that it works fine

How come I can access this post directly but not through the graph api?

---

Comment: Missing? Are you sure you are not getting some paginated results?

Comment: I'm sure. Even in the 1st 25 results - some are missing (for example - I receive posts number 1,2,4,5,6,8,9.... 3 and 7 are missing. I can see them in the group - but not in the graph explorer results.

Comment: Can you extract those posts individually if you provide their id?

Comment: Please see the "Try it yourself" section I've added just now.
Lix - That's a good question. I'm not sure how to find the post's ID since it doesn't appear in the query results.

Comment: You might need to inspect the actual UI element within Facebook and find the id attribute there.

Comment: Lix, Brilliant. I've tried to access the specific post using the graph explorer and received (while with other posts it worked fine):

{
  "error": {
    "message": "No node specified", 
    "type": "GraphMethodException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}

Comment: I've added the Do It Yourself section again....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SOLVED!!!! (well, more or less)

I've approached some of the people who posted the posts that cannot be accessed via Graph API.

After some debugging we have found the source.

They all turnd off the Facebook Platform option: https://www.facebook.com/about/privacy/your-info-on-other#friendsapps

This stops apps from accessing their data.

It doesn't really helps me with my project, but at-least I feel better. ;)

Enjoy